# Records from the last fully completed week (i.e. from Monday to Sunday) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the records that were `created_at` during the last fully completed week - i.e. between last Monday and last Sunday?

To be absolutely clear, if today was Wednesday 10 July, I would want the records between very early morning Monday 1 July and very late evening Sunday 7 July. If it were Friday 12 July, I would ***still*** want the records between Monday 1 July and very late evening Sunday 7 July. But if it was Monday 15 July, I would want records between Monday 8 July and very late evening Sunday 14 July

How can I achieve this?

#### Note

I can easily get a rolling week's records, i.e. the records [between the current time and one week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498110/show-only-posts-created-in-last-week) (i.e. `Time.now - 7.days`). This is **not** what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get last week with `Time.now - 7.days`, and then get the beginning and end of that week with `start_date = (Time.now - 7.days).beginning_of_week` and `end_date = (Time.now - 7.days).end_of_week`.

Then you can query like `Model.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_date, end_date)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
start_date = (Date.today - 1.week).beginning_of_week.beginning_of_day
end_date   = (Date.today - 1.week).end_of_week.end_of_day
```

Do not forget about timezones if it matters. Good luck